# Any way to combine these 3 SQL Queries Together?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 separate queries at the moment that I'm trying to combine together so it is more efficient.

The reason I'm putting them together is so that I can sort all of the results by `submitdate`, as of right now they are sorted by `submitdate` but are separated by each query.

First is

> Query that gets all posts that I have commented on that have new comments

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*,c.submitdate as MostRecentSubmitDate
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN comments c
ON c.postid = p.id
WHERE c.submitdate > (
   SELECT MAX(c2.submitdate)
   FROM comments c2
   WHERE c2.postid = c.postid
   AND c2.deviceID = ?
)
```

Second is

> Query that gets most recent replies on my posts.

```
SELECT p.PostTitle,p.id AS PostID,c1.id AS CommentID, c1.comment, q.LatestCommentDate, c1.deviceID
FROM (SELECT c.postid, MAX(c.SubmitDate) AS LatestCommentDate 
FROM comments c GROUP BY c.postid) q 
INNER JOIN posts p ON q.postid = p.id and ? = p.deviceiD 
INNER JOIN comments c1 ON q.LatestCommentDate = c1.submitDate
```

Third is

> Query that gets the amount of votes on each of my posts

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE DEVICEID = ?
AND PostVotes > 0
ORDER BY SUBMITDATE
```

Comment: what fields you want in your final output, after combining these there queries. Please look for the proper JOIN as for your requirement.

Comment: @user4221591 I would want all fields in my final output. I can sort that out after I figure out how I would mesh the queries together

Comment: You need to use `UNION` between your queries. Just make sure the number of fields and data types should be the same for each query.

Comment: @sqluser Thanks for your response, could you give an example of what that might look like for my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION` to combine all your queries together.

Rules to make a `UNION`

1. The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
2. The data types must be compatible.

---

```
query 1

UNION

query 2

UNION

query 3

ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: what if I dont have the same order in columns? It will just display null inside the row  or will it throw an error?

Comment: You need to make `NULL` instead of any of missing ones in your `SELECT` statement.